# Projection of a set $G_\delta$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, descriptive-set-theory

The canonical projection
$\pi:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi(x,y)=x$

maps $G_\delta$ sets to Borel sets? i.e.

If $A=\cap_n^\infty A_n$ with $A_n$ open sets, then $\pi(A)$ is Borel?

Comment: As William said, the continuous image of a Borel set need not be Borel. However, it is true that a continuous injective image of a Borel set (in particular a $G_\delta$ set) is Borel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Even projections of $G_\delta$ sets could be non-Borel. A projection of a $G_\delta$ subset of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is called an analytic set. There are analytic non-Borel sets.

---

There are also many very concrete examples of analytic not Borel Sets. Often, they are more naturally subsets of other Polish spaces such as ${}^\omega \omega$; however, one can always transfer them into $\mathbb{R}$ by a Borel isomorphism.

For example, the set of reals that do not code well-ordering is an analytic not Borel set. Isomorphism of structures in the language with one binary relation symbol is also analytic. There are also numerous other examples from analysis concerning concepts like differentiability, summability, etc. See *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* Section 27 for other examples.

Comment: thanks for answering! wanted to find out whether I can apply the result to prove that $\pi(f^{-1}(0,1))$ not is Borel  measurable where $f=\limsup_{n\rightarrow \infty }f_n$ and $f_n: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are continuous, although my teacher says that $\pi(f^{-1}(0,1))$ is Borel

Comment: Projections of closed sets are always Borel, because every closed set is $\sigma$-compact, hence the same is true of its projection.

Comment: @Helmonio: Do you mean $f_n : \Bbb{R}^2 \to \Bbb{R}$ instead of $f_n : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}$?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Yes, I would greatly appreciate if you could guide me

Comment: According to this post http://mathoverflow.net/questions/34142/projection-of-borel-set-from-r2-to-r1 , the analytic subsets of $\Bbb{R}$ are precisely the projections of $G_\delta$ subsets of $\Bbb{R}^2$. As there are non-Borel analytic sets, this shows that projections of $G_\delta$s are not Borel in general.

Comment: @PhoemueX Yes. Analytic sets are projections of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R} \times {}^\omega \omega$ and not projection of closed subsets of $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. If the second coordinate space is compact (or $\sigma$-compact), the analytic sets are generally the projection of $G_\delta$ sets. I will edit the post shortly.

Comment: @PhoemueX: “the set of reals that do not code well-ordering”? What does this mean? What does this set look like?